# Access Table Field (Cutting out certain number of characters from beginning of data)

Tags: ms-access

I am working in basic access and I want to trim from beginning of data in a field the first two characters. e.g. Extract "cdefghi" from data currently showing "abcdefghi". The length of the field however could be different so I can't simply use the "Right" function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways; Mid() or Right()

The Mid() function allows you to begin from any point in the string.  By leaving the optional end point blank, you can just trim the first 2 characters off by using:

```
X = Mid(Trim(MyField), 3)
```

The Right() function allows you to take as many characters from the right of the string as you want.  In this case, you want 2 less than the number of characters in the field:

```
X = Right(Trim(MyField), Len(Trim(MyField)) - 2)
```

**Always remember to trim your values!**  You may have some leading/trailing spaces in your fields.